# Order a "mixed" vector (numbers with letters)

Tags: r, sorting

How can I order a vector like

```
c("7","10a","10b","10c","8","9","11c","11b","11a","12") -> alph
```

in

```
alph
[1] "7","8","9","10a","10b","10c","11a","11b","11c","12"
```

and use it to sort a data.frame, like

```
V1 <- c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","E","E")
V2 <- 2:1 
V3 <- alph
df <- data.frame(V1,V2,V3)
```

and order the row to obtain (order V2 and then V3)

```
 V1 V2  V3
C  1   9
A  1 10a
B  1 10c
D  1 11b
E  1  12
A  2   7
C  2   8
B  2 10b
E  2 11a
D  2 11c
```

Comment: Do not use `data.frame(cbind(...))`, just use `data.frame(...)` directly. By calling `cbind` you make a *character matrix* containing `V1`, `V2` and `V3`, which probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
> library(gtools)
> mixedsort(alph)

[1] "7"   "8"   "9"   "10a" "10b" "10c" "11a" "11b" "11c" "12"
```

To sort a data.frame you use `mixedorder` instead

```
> mydf <- data.frame(alph, USArrests[seq_along(alph),])
> mydf[mixedorder(mydf$alph),]

            alph Murder Assault UrbanPop Rape
Alabama        7   13.2     236       58 21.2
California     8    9.0     276       91 40.6
Colorado       9    7.9     204       78 38.7
Alaska       10a   10.0     263       48 44.5
Arizona      10b    8.1     294       80 31.0
Arkansas     10c    8.8     190       50 19.5
Florida      11a   15.4     335       80 31.9
Delaware     11b    5.9     238       72 15.8
Connecticut  11c    3.3     110       77 11.1
Georgia       12   17.4     211       60 25.8
```

### `mixedorder` on multiple vectors (columns)

Apparently `mixedorder` cannot handle multiple vectors. I have made a function that circumvents this by converting all character vectors to factors *with mixedsorted sorted levels*, and pass all vectors on to the standard `order` function.

```
multi.mixedorder <- function(..., na.last = TRUE, decreasing = FALSE){
    do.call(order, c(
        lapply(list(...), function(l){
            if(is.character(l)){
                factor(l, levels=mixedsort(unique(l)))
            } else {
                l
            }
        }),
        list(na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)
    ))
}
```

However, in your particular case `multi.mixedorder` gets you the same result as the standard `order`, since `V2` is numeric.

```
df <- data.frame(
    V1 = c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","E","E"),
    V2 = 19:10,
    V3 = alph,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df[multi.mixedorder(df$V2, df$V3),]

   V1 V2  V3
10  E 10  12
9   E 11 11a
8   D 12 11b
7   D 13 11c
6   C 14   9
5   C 15   8
4   B 16 10c
3   B 17 10b
2   A 18 10a
1   A 19   7
```

#### Notice that

- `19:10` is equivalent to `c(19:10)`. `c` means *concat*, that is to make one long vector out of many short, but in you case you only have one vector (`19:10`) so there's no need to concat anything. However, in the case of `V1` you have 10 vectors of length 1, so there you need to concat, as you already do.
- You need `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to not convert `V1` and `V3` to (incorrectly sorted) factors (which is default).

Comment: I tried this solution but i can't figure out how to use it to sort two columns (I edited an example).

Comment: It appears `mixedorder` does not support multiple columns (how strange!), but I can hack you a roundabout solution. Been wanting to do a thing of this nature before.

Comment: You're right, my example is really bad, sorry. But try your solution with
V2 = 2:1
and it's not working anymore... isn't?

Comment: Don't worry, many things in R are not obvious at first :) And you are correct in that it doesn't work if there are ties in `V2`. I'll take a look at it later today.

Comment: There! Works now. The trick was to convert all characters to factors, which are sorted correctly with the standard `order` function.

Comment: Great! I made some editing to include all your useful comments. Thanks!

Comment: this helped me thanks.But ggplot insists in plotting in the unsorted form

Comment: @TiagoBruno Make sure you are using the newest version of ggplot2 that was recently released. The ordering of things has been a pain in older versions and although I have not tried it in the new version yet I know it has been massively rewritten and improved, so I hope they have sorted this out.