# how to sort data frame by column names in R?

Tags: r

How can I sort the below data frame `df` to `df1`?

```
df
a1 a4 a3 a5 a2
```

sorted data frame

```
df1
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5
```

Comment: `df[ , order(names(df))]` ?

Comment: Not sure if we can close this with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396582/order-a-mixed-vector-numbers-with-letters)

Comment: @David that's a good target

Comment: @PierreLafortune the dupe about sorting rows, not columns though- so not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order a "mixed" vector (numbers with letters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396582/order-a-mixed-vector-numbers-with-letters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `mixedorder` from `library(gtools)`

```
library(gtools)
df1 <- df[mixedorder(colnames(df))]
df1
#   a1 a3 a9 a10
#1  1  3  1   2
#2  2  4  2   3
#3  3  5  3   4
#4  4  6  4   5
#5  5  7  5   6
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a1 = 1:5, a10=2:6, a3 = 3:7, a9= 1:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

In base `R`, assuming the numbers in the `colnames` don't go into double digits.

```
df
#  a1 a4 a3 a5 a2
#1  1  4  3  5  2

df[, order(names(df))]
#  a1 a2 a3 a4 a5
#1  1  2  3  4  5
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this safe enough. For instance `order(c("a2", "a10"))` will give a wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no "hole" in the numbers suffixing the columns names, you can also use dplyr:

`library(dplyr)
df1 <- select(df, num_range("a", 1:4))`