# How to do a sort of mixed values in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-munging

I have a data frame that I want to sort by one column than the next, (using tidyverse if possible).

I checked the below address but the solutions did not seem to work.

[Order a "mixed" vector (numbers with letters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396582/order-a-mixed-vector-numbers-with-letters)

Sample code for an example:

```
variable <- c("channel", "channel", "channel", "comp_ded", "comp_ded", "comp_ded")
level <- c("DIR", "EA", "IA", "500", "750", "1000")
df <- as_tibble(cbind(variable, level))
```

This does not give me what I want:

```
df <- df %>% arrange(variable, level)
```

The order of the level columns are as follows:

`variable level
channel  DIR
channel  EA
channel  IA
level    1000
level    500
level    750`

I need them:

`variable level
channel  DIR
channel  EA
channel  IA
level    500
level    750
level    1000`

There are multiple different "variables" in the real data set where half need to be sorted in number order and half in alphabetical.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's slightly ugly, but you could just split the data frame in two using filter statements, arrange each section individually, and then bind them back together:

```
df <- bind_rows(df %>%
              filter(!is.na(as.numeric(level))) %>%
              arrange(variable, as.numeric(level)),
          df %>%
              filter(is.na(as.numeric(level))) %>%
              arrange(variable, level))
```

Gives you:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  variable level
  <chr>    <chr>
1 comp_ded 500  
2 comp_ded 750  
3 comp_ded 1000 
4 channel  DIR  
5 channel  EA   
6 channel  IA
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be to use `dplyr::group_by`.

```
library(dplyr)

variable <- c("channel", "channel", "channel", "comp_ded", "comp_ded", "comp_ded")
level <- c("DIR", "EA", "IA", "500", "750", "1000")
df <- as_tibble(cbind(variable, level))

df %>%
  group_by(variable, level) %>%
  arrange()

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  variable  level
     <chr> <fctr>
1 comp_ded    DIR
2 comp_ded     EA
3 comp_ded     IA
4  channel    500
5  channel    750
6  channel   1000
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `gtools`, a slightly shorter solution which uses `mixedorder`:

```
library(gtools)
sorteddf <- df[with(df, order(variable, mixedorder(level))),]
```

Output:

```
  variable level
1 channel  DIR  
2 channel  EA   
3 channel  IA   
4 comp_ded 500  
5 comp_ded 750  
6 comp_ded 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a temporary variable for sorting. Once you've sorted in the desired order, you can also set the order permanently by converting to factor (as in @Vio's answer). Maybe something like this:

```
df = df %>% 
  mutate(tmp = as.numeric(level)) %>% 
  arrange(variable, tmp, level) %>% 
  select(-tmp) %>% 
  mutate(level = factor(level, levels=unique(level)))
```

> ```
>   variable level
>   <chr>    <fct>
> 1 channel  DIR  
> 2 channel  EA   
> 3 channel  IA   
> 4 comp_ded 500  
> 5 comp_ded 750  
> 6 comp_ded 1000
> ```

I think you can also shorten this by not explicitly creating a temporary variable, and instead using an "anonymous" variable inside `arrange`:

```
df = df %>% 
  arrange(variable, as.numeric(level), level) %>% 
  mutate(level = factor(level, levels=unique(level)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert to factor and change the levels. Even easier with `forcats::fct_relevel()`

```
# Convert to factor
df <- as_tibble(cbind(variable, level)) %>%
  mutate(level = as.factor(level))

# Change order of levels
levels(df$level) = levels(df$level)[match(c("DIR", "EA", "IA", "500", "750", "1000"), levels(df$level))]

df %>% arrange(level)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  variable  level
     <chr> <fctr>
1 comp_ded    DIR
2 comp_ded     EA
3 comp_ded     IA
4  channel    500
5  channel    750
6  channel   1000
```

Comment: This makes sense for the example.  My real data set has 220 observations

Comment: @Jordan It changes the levels of the factor. It will work on any number of observations since you are sorting factors (which is sorted by the ordering of its level). If you have more levels, define their ordering manually. Or if you are looking for simple A-Z, 0-9 sort for more than 6 factor levels, then split sorting is probably the best way.

Comment: split sorting?  I'll have to look that up..  It's 10 different variables and levels within those.  Thanks.

Comment: By split, I meant the way divibisan's answer is sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's much easier to sort by `as.numeric(level)` first, then by `level`:

```
df %>% arrange(variable, as.numeric(level), level)
```

Gives:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
variable level
<chr>    <chr>
1 channel  DIR
2 channel  EA
3 channel  IA
4 comp_ded 500
5 comp_ded 750
6 comp_ded 1000
```