# How should I order a column with character values numerically

Tags: r

If i have a matrix that looks like this:

```
        Region                    Ålder     Antal   regpop    Andel                 
   [1,] "01 Stockholms län"       "0 år"    "28474" "2377081" "0.0119785568939384"  
   [2,] "01 Stockholms län"       "1 år"    "29033" "2377081" "0.0122137192632477"  
   [3,] "01 Stockholms län"       "10 år"   "29678" "2377081" "0.0124850604586045"  
   [4,] "01 Stockholms län"       "100+ år" "524"   "2377081" "0.000220438428475933"
   [5,] "01 Stockholms län"       "11 år"   "29679" "2377081" "0.0124854811426283"  
   [6,] "01 Stockholms län"       "12 år"   "28956" "2377081" "0.0121813265934144"  
   [7,] "01 Stockholms län"       "13 år"   "28592" "2377081" "0.0120281976087479"
   [8,] "01 Stockholms län"       "14 år"   "27572" "2377081" "0.0115990999044627"  
   [9,] "01 Stockholms län"       "15 år"   "27466" "2377081" "0.0115545073979389"  
  [10,] "01 Stockholms län"       "16 år"   "26691" "2377081" "0.0112284772794869"  
  [11,] "01 Stockholms län"       "17 år"   "26004" "2377081" "0.0109394673551301"  
  [12,] "01 Stockholms län"       "18 år"   "24996" "2377081" "0.0105154178591306"  
  [13,] "01 Stockholms län"       "19 år"   "24971" "2377081" "0.0105049007585354"  
  [14,] "01 Stockholms län"       "2 år"    "29268" "2377081" "0.0123125800088428"  
  [15,] "01 Stockholms län"       "20 år"   "24777" "2377081" "0.0104232880579164"
```

what should i do to order them from "0 år", "1 år", "2 år" ....."100+ år"

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396582/order-a-mixed-vector-numbers-with-letters

Answer (score 2):

The `gtools::mixedsort` function can help here

```
x <- c("0 år", "1 år", "10 år", "100+ år", "11 år", "12 år", "13 år", 
  "14 år", "15 år", "16 år", "17 år", "18 år", "19 år", "2 år", 
  "20 år")

gtools::mixedsort(x)
#  [1] "0 år"    "1 år"    "2 år"    "10 år"   "11 år"   "12 år"   "13 år"   "14 år"  
#  [9] "15 år"   "16 år"   "17 år"   "18 år"   "19 år"   "20 år"   "100+ år"
```

If the object you shared is a matrix named `data`, then you could do

```
data[gtools::mixedorder(data[["Ålder"]]),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option. Extract the digits from the string using `gsub` and then convert to a numeric allowing us to reorder numerically. I have created a mock matrix just as an example. Perhaps if you could provide the actual matrix by using dput i.e. dput(matrix) then paste the output into your question, that would help people give more specific answers

```
x <- c("0 år", "1 år", "10 år", "100+ år", "11 år", "12 år", "13 år", 
       "14 år", "15 år", "16 år", "17 år", "18 år", "19 år", "2 år", 
       "20 år")

y <- 1:length(x)

mat <- matrix(c(x, y), ncol = 2)

mat[order(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", mat[,1]))),]
```