# Sorting a dataframe in R

Tags: r, sorting

I am trying to sort a dataframe in ascending order which I'm confused at.

Example:

```
Label | Data
B3        2
B1        3
B2        4
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
Label | Data
B1        3
B2        4
B3        2
```

**I am using R without any Library.**

Comment: `dplyr::arrange(mydf, Label)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order a "mixed" vector (numbers with letters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396582/order-a-mixed-vector-numbers-with-letters)

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can use `order`:

```
Label <- c("B3","B1","B2")
Data <- c(2,3,4)
df <- data.frame(Label,Data)
> df
  Label Data
1    B3    2
2    B1    3
3    B2    4
df = df[order(Label),]
> df
  Label Data
2    B1    3
3    B2    4
1    B3    2
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use `tidyverse` later, with `dplyr` you can use `arrange`:

```
Label <- c("B3","B1","B2")
Data <- c(2,3,4)
df <- data.frame(Label,Data)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  arrange(Label)

  Label Data
1    B1    3
2    B2    4
3    B3    2
```