# ggplot : change order in each group of levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to do a barplot with ggplot, samples grouped by type and for each type grouped by another formula (alphabatically or regex or whatever)

I have a dataframe with sample name, a type for each sample and a value for each sample

Here is a reproducible example.

```
mydf <- data.frame(sample=c("A877","A110","A56","A1302","A1230"), type=c("virus","bacteria","bacteria","virus","bacteria"), expr=c(3,5,7,2,6))


sample  type     expr

A877    virus      3
A110    bacteria   5
A56     bacteria   7
A1302   virus      2
A1230   bacteria   6
```

I create a factor for the "type" column as this :

```
mydf$type <- factor(mydf$type, levels=c("virus","bacteria"))
```

Then I apply to the column "sample" the same order than the column "type" thanks to the levels:

```
mydf$sample <- factor(mydf$sample, levels=mydf$sample[order(mydf$type)])
```

Finaly I plot the barplot :

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(x=sample, y=expr, fill=type)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

The result is :

[image]

I need to order virus and bacteria sample name alphabetically. It's ok for virus but bacteria are with this order : A110/A56/A1230 but I need : A56/A110/A1230

Any clue ? Thanx !

Edit:

The solution provides by Gregor Thomas works well but...if I add another kind of data, it doesn't work anymore...

Let's say I have this more complicated vector :

```
phage <- c( "T2505", "T815", "T3046", "T943", "T518", "T1382-2", "T413", "T2307", "T1382-1", "T289-3")
```

To sort it alphabetically I tried the Gregor's solution :

```
phage[gtools::mixedorder(phage)]
[1] "T289-3"  "T413"    "T518"    "T815"    "T943"    "T1382-2" "T1382-1" "T2307"   "T2505"   "T3046"
```

hummmm it almost works...

I found this solution on Google, it SEEMS to work better :

```
stringr::str_sort(phage, numeric = T)
[1] "T289-3"  "T413"    "T518"    "T815"    "T943"    "T1382-1" "T1382-2" "T2307"   "T2505"   "T3046"
```

BUT : if I try to use it in my first example, the barplot sample names are NOT ordered as it does

With gtools::mixedsort :

```
phage <- c( "T2505", "T815", "T3046", "T943", "T518", "T1382-2", "T413", "T2307", "T1382-1", "T289-3")
phage_expr <- c(4,3,7,3,4,1,2,6,4,8)
mydf <- data.frame(sample=c("A877","A110","A56","A1302","A1230", phage), type=c("virus","bacteria","bacteria","virus","bacteria", rep("phage", 10)), expr=c(3,5,7,2,6, phage_expr))
mydf$type <- factor(mydf$type, levels=c("virus","phage","bacteria"))
mydf$sample <- factor(mydf$sample,  levels = mydf$sample[order(mydf$type, gtools::mixedorder(mydf$sample))])
ggplot(mydf, aes(x=sample, y=expr, fill=type)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

With stringr::str_sort :

```
phage <- c( "T2505", "T815", "T3046", "T943", "T518", "T1382-2", "T413", "T2307", "T1382-1", "T289-3")
phage_expr <- c(4,3,7,3,4,1,2,6,4,8)
mydf <- data.frame(sample=c("A877","A110","A56","A1302","A1230", phage), type=c("virus","bacteria","bacteria","virus","bacteria", rep("phage", 10)), expr=c(3,5,7,2,6, phage_expr))
mydf$type <- factor(mydf$type, levels=c("virus","phage","bacteria"))
mydf$sample <- factor(mydf$sample,  levels = mydf$sample[order(mydf$type, stringr::str_sort(mydf$sample, numeric=T))])
ggplot(mydf, aes(x=sample, y=expr, fill=type)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

None of them give the expected result when I use the gtools or stringr with a single vector !

Thanx for your help

Comment: Regarding your edits: (a) Please stop referring to the sorting you want as "alphabetical". The default sorting is alphabetical. The alphabetical sorting of the numbers `1, 2, 3, 101, 112, 1115` is `1, 101, 1115, 112, 2, 3`. **You do not want alphabetical sorting.** Alphabetical sorting is what you get when you use `order()` without modifications. (b) Please be clear about your expected result. With the more complicated `phage` vector you've shown two things that don't achieve your desired result, but you have not told us what your desired result is.

Comment: Your labels are getting complicated enough, your best bet may be to split them into components and sort those. Create a column with the leading letter(s), then the number(s) before the `-`, then any number(s) after the dash, then you can sort by those three columns in order. If you convert the numeric component columns to `numeric` class, then you don't need to worry about alphabetical sorting being applied incorrectly to numbers, so you can just use the base `order` function, something like `order(letter_component, numeric_component_1, numeric_component_2)`---assuming that's your goal.

Comment: @GregorThomas  Sorry for misunderstanding, yes when I said "alphabeticaly" I mean that for example T34-3 comes first then T34-5, it was clear for me, sorry if it was not clear for you. Which term sould I use for this kind of ordering ? alphabetically/numericaly ? I would edit my post with this term. Thanx for your advice to split my string into columns, I thought about it but I thought that a simpliest soultion was available.

Comment: "Mixed ordering" is the only term I've heard, as in the `gtools::mixedorder` function that we used.

Answer (score 1):

You can give multiple columns/vectors to `order` to work as tie breakers. In this case, `levels = mydf$sample[order(mydf$type, mydf$sample)]` should work, it will order the `sample` levels first by `type`, then by `sample`.

```
mydf$sample <- factor(mydf$sample, levels = mydf$sample[order(mydf$type, mydf$sample)] )

ggplot(mydf, aes(x=sample, y=expr, fill=type)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

This shows alphabetical ordering.

> I  need to order virus and bacteria sample name alphabetically...
>
> I need : A56/A110/A1230

Alphabetical ordering considers digits one at a time, so `A1...` comes before `A5...` no matter what `...` is. To get your described result, you need a "mixed ordering" that considers letters alphabetically and numbers numerically. You can [find a question all about mixed ordering here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396582/order-a-mixed-vector-numbers-with-letters), a nice way to do it is with `gtools::mixedorder`

```
mydf$sample <- factor(
  mydf$sample,
  levels = mydf$sample[order(mydf$type, gtools::mixedorder(mydf$sample))]
)

ggplot(mydf, aes(x=sample, y=expr, fill=type)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx for your answer. It works but when I try with a more complicated vector, it doesnt work anymore. I edited my post with your answer and a new vector for "phage" names