`mixedorder` sorting of a data.table with vector of column names as input
This is my sample data:
library(data.table)
set.seed(47)
colsize <- 10
DT <- data.table(sortcol1 = as.numeric(sample(CJ(1:27,1:27,1:27)[,paste0(V1,V2,V3)],colsize)),
               sortcol2 = sample(CJ(c( LETTERS, " "),c(1:27),c(letters," "))[,paste0(V1,V2,V3)],colsize),
               sortcol3 = sample(CJ(c( LETTERS, " "),c(1:27),c(letters," "))[,paste0(V1,V2,V3)],colsize),
               sortcol4 = sample(CJ(c( LETTERS, " "),c(1:27),c(letters," "))[,paste0(V1,V2,V3)],colsize),
               sortcol5 = sample(CJ(c( LETTERS, " "),c(1:27),c(letters," "))[,paste0(V1,V2,V3)],colsize),
               stringsAsFactors = F)

DT
#     sortcol1 sortcol2 sortcol3 sortcol4 sortcol5
#        <num>   <char>   <char>   <char>   <char>
#  1:   241420     F12e     V10y     D23v     J10b
#  2:    71714      P1j     Q11y      D3s     F11e
#  3:    18617      E3w     U18t      25n     L14r
#  4:     4254     A12i     P15f     I27h      L9m
#  5:   131325     K27w      E8j      B6q       1q
#  6:     1958      Q1k     H23u     A18f     P23 
#  7:   151619      C1y      R7i      27q     U26l
#  8:     9262      C9n     N15o     P19q      I7t
#  9:    11518      C8l     P22a      E5g     X18z
# 10:     3224     Z26b     X17b      Y5z     Q12k

This is a user input from another source:
input = c("sortcol2", "sortcol1");

This solves the purpose but I need it to be dynamic incorporating the object input
library(gtools)
DT[mixedorder(sortcol2, sortcol1 , decreasing = FALSE)]

DT has a mix of numeric, characters or both. some columns can be entirely numeric.
input can be of length at least 1. It can be in any order.
## sample input values
input <- c("sortcol3","sortcol1")
input <- c("sortcol5")
input <- c("sortcol1","sortcol5","sortcol3") # etc

data.table::setorderv does not take into account mixed alpha and numeric values in a vector.
I need this to be in data.table.

Looking at this a little more, I don't think your example works like you think it does. mixedorder, unlike order, only takes a single vector to sort. If we use a simpler example that has duplicates so that the second sort column is needed as a tie-breaker (unlike in your sample data where only the first column is needed): dt = data.table(a = c("A1", "A1", "A11", "A11", "A2", "A2", "A2"), b = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3)) then you can see that dt[mixedorder(a, b , decreasing = FALSE)] sorts by a but ignores b.

Your real need (or at least the first step) is  a generalization of mixedorder that takes one or more vectors as inputs.

Agree, real need is generalization of mixedorder.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20396604/903061 which provides multi.mixedorder

Thanks, I have edited the question. This seems to solve my problem. I am testing it thoroughly.  However I am still looking for a better answer.

What are you looking for in an answer that would make it "better"?

I have used it many times and different type of data. I think I do not have any complaints so far.

Why don't you add your "possible solution" as an answer to your question? This is encouraged (and editing questions to include solutions is discouraged).  It won't prevent someone else from contributing a better answer, if they have one.

Ok. This isn’t my work but someone else’s. I wanted to check if I am allowed to answer my questions or not. I will answer this question now as you say that it is encouraged.

Possible solution
This function seems to be working well. I have edited it to incorporate input.
multi.mixedorder <-\(data, cols, na.last = TRUE, decreasing = FALSE) {
  do.call(order, c(
    lapply(cols, function(col) {
      if (is.character(data[[col]])) {
        factor(data[[col]], levels = mixedsort(unique(data[[col]])))
      } else {
        data[[col]]
      }
    }),
    list(na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)
  ))
}

DT[multi.mixedorder(DT, input),]

